# How to change this class into a functional component in react native

Tags: react-native, axios, react-hooks

Hello I'm using this axios wrapper in my project ,it's working as expected.But I want to use hooks in this class so I must change this into a functional component.Any ideas to change this into a functional component.Thanks...

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import createAuthRefreshInterceptor from 'axios-auth-refresh';

const axiosApiInstance = axios.create({baseURL: "http://10.0.2.2:5001"});
const refreshAuthLogic = (failedRequest) => {
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://10.0.2.2:5001/api/token/refresh',
    data: {
      email: 'rwar@gmail.com',
      refreshToken: 'testrefreshtoken'
    },
  };
  return axios(options, {
    pauseInstanceWhileRefreshing: true,
  }).then((tokenRefreshResponse) => {
    failedRequest.response.config.headers['Authorization'] =
      'Bearer ' + tokenRefreshResponse.data.result.token;
    return Promise.resolve();
  });
};
createAuthRefreshInterceptor(axiosApiInstance, refreshAuthLogic);
axiosApiInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      // 401 error redirect to login
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    if (error.response.status !== 401) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    }
  },
);
export default axiosApiInstance;
```

Comment: this is not a react class component.

Comment: yes ,it's just a api wrapper with axios .I want to use useContext in this wrapper.Any way to achive this? Thanks...

Comment: how do you want to use the context? you can probably just pass it into the wrapper like an argument?

Comment: I have a context for storing user information and tokens and  some functions about authentication.I know I can achieve my aim without using context ,instead of using context,I can include that functions to this api wrapper and use them internally.But I just want to learn if there is any way to use hook (usecontext) in this axios api wrapper.

Comment: you can only use hooks in a react function component. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html